# I was trying to solve a problem in codingbat.com problem name is "lucky_sum"

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Given 3 `int` values, `a b c`, return their sum. However, if one of the values is `13` then it does not count towards the `sum` and `values` to its right does not count. So for example, if `b` is `13`, then both `b` and `c` does not count. For example:

```
lucky_sum(1, 2, 3) → 6

lucky_sum(1, 2, 13) → 3

lucky_sum(1, 13, 3) → 1

lucky_sum(1, 13, 13) → 1
```

Below is my solution. I can't understand what's wrong in my code.

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    list1 = [a, b, c]
    list2 = []
    for x in list1:
        if x is not 13:
            list2.append(x)
    return sum(list2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code fixed in your way:

```
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    list1 = [a, b, c]
    list2 = []
    for x in list1:
        if x is not 13:
            list2.append(x)
        else:
            break
    return sum(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning values after 13. If you get to 13, you're supposed to break out of the loop and return the sum.

Comment: Not part of your question, but I'd do `[sum(list1) if 13 not in list1 else sum(list1[:list1.index(13)])]`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution correctly ignores 13s in the numbers, but the second requirement of "...and values to its right do not count" is not respected by your code. Try to `break` out of the loop as soon as you find a 13.

**Edit**

BTW, the most pythonic solution would be something like:

```
from itertools import takewhile
def lucky_sum(*args):
    return sum(takewhile(lambda x: x != 13, args))
```

Works with any number of parameters and is really easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

## Here is my answer for this one:

```py
def lucky_sum(a, b, c):
    total = a, b, c
    new_list = []
    for i in total:
        if i == 13:
            break
        else:
            new_list.append(i)
    return sum(new_list)
```